# PIL Image.open creates corrupted image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

Python's `PIL` module has been working fine for me in past projects, but I noticed that for certain images when opening and showing the color is corrupted, while for other images it is fine. However, saving it is fine for both images. Is there a reason why this only works for some images?

---

### Example:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("banana.png")
img.convert("RGBA")
img.show()
img.save('out.png')
img1 = Image.open("banana2.png")
img1.convert("RGBA")
img1.show()
img1.save('out2.png')
```

---

#### Original Images

[image: banana.png][image: banana2.png]

#### Shown Images

[image: tmpi8l0e6nk.png][image: tmpnr61e6ib.png]

#### Saved Images

[image: out.png][image: out2.png]

---

Furthermore, I only noticed one difference between the two images; `banana.png` has no color profile, while `banana2.png` does. Both are located in the same directory as well. I am not sure whether this has to do with the problem; it is just an observation.

Also, when reading pixel data in images, `banana.png` returns `0` whereas `banana2.png` returns `(0,0,0,0)` on a transparent pixel. Again, this is just an observation.

#### Original File Information

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated!

---

### Edit:

Running our program **without** convert has the same result:

#### Shown Images:

[image: tmpj6g2tkbk.png][image: tmppq7nt2zg.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it's related to calling `convert("RGBA")` on an image without a color profile. PIL could require that information.

P.S. Have you tried seeing if it's still corrupted when calling `show()` without `convert()`?

Here's the `PIL convert` source code https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert

Comment: Yes, without convert the same thing happens. Also, why the image is saved correctly has not been explained.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107694/opening-png-with-pil-pillow/29108827#29108827

Answer (score 0):

When PIL displays an image with `show` it removes all transparency. The easiest way to do this is to just pass along whatever color values exist in those transparent areas. This will depend on the application that created the images.

Your first image has random image colors in the transparent areas, while the second one uses white.